# Python: 3D clustering of lists based on their absolute number of same strings content

Tags: python, string, list, cluster-analysis

I have hundreds of lists containing strings of names, and I want to cluster them on 3D graph. Here I give example of 3 lists. The lists with most number of same strings content should be closer to the other on the graph.

How can I do it?

```
person1 = ['mike', 'alex', 'arker','locke','dave','david','ross','rachel','anna','ann','darl','carl','karle']

person2 = ['mika', 'adlex', 'parker','ocke','ave','david','rosse','rachel','anna','ann','darla','carla','karle']

person3 = ['mika', 'alex', 'parker','ocke','ave','david','rosse','ross','anna','ann','darla','carla','karle', 'sasha', 'daria']
```

Comment: "*The lists with most number of same strings content should be closer to the other on the graph*" or in other words??..

Comment: Essentially, think of every list as 1 person. And strings inside this list as his/her friends. Persons with the most number of friends should be closer dots to other persons/lists with same friends on this 3D graph.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you'll need is counters which represent the amount of equal strings between two lists:

```
person1 = ['mike', 'alex', 'arker','locke','dave','david','ross','rachel','anna','ann','darl','carl','karle']
person2 = ['mika', 'adlex', 'parker','ocke','ave','david','rosse','rachel','anna','ann','darla','carla','karle']
person3 = ['mika', 'alex', 'parker','ocke','ave','david','rosse','ross','anna','ann','darla','carla','karle', 'sasha', 'daria']
resourceLists = [person1, person2, person3]
equalsList = []
for index, list in enumerate(resourceLists):
hitList = [0] * len(resourceLists)
if (index + 1 < len(resourceLists)):
    nextList = resourceLists[index+1]
    for iNext, x in enumerate(nextList):
        if x in list:
            hitList[index + 1] += 1
equalsList.append(hitList)
print equalsList
```

output of this code will give: [[0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 11], [0, 0, 0]] for your current example. Now you can loop these lists and find the amount if equal strings between each list. So between list 1 and 2 you see in the first list the 5 (first list, second position) which means 5 equal strings between person1 and person2. The second list in equalsList compares the second personList with the following lists, so you see 11 hits with the third list. Note that this script only looks to later lists for amount of equal strings, so each combination is only checked once: When going through person2 I'm not revisiting the first list to search for equal strings, because I already have them at that point.

Comment: Thanks, but the code has a lot of indent fails. 
And I wanted a 3D graph with lists shown as points on graph.
I know how to sort it outside the graph

Comment: Indent failure is probably a copy/paste error: I copied this straight from working code. For putting in a graph, I know that https://plot.ly/python/3d-network-graph/ looks like what you ask, but I'm not sure if it is what you had in mind, so perhaps you should look around there and see which one works best for you: they have tutorials on how to implement them which are pretty clear I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Set intersection can be used as a similarity metric for hierarchical clustering. See, e.g., Jaccard and dice coefficients.

Then you can cluster, but I don't see how this relates to 3D...